# Laravel Query Builder Join is diffrent from RAW

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel Query Builder to join two table from mysql db
When i use raw query in the shell

```
SELECT * from parent_accounts
LEFT JOIN child_accounts on parent_accounts.account_id=child_accounts.parent_id
```

Result

[image]

When using laravel Query Builderas follows

```
 $accounts=\DB::table('parent_accounts as p')->join('child_accounts as c','p.account_id','=','c.parent_id')->select('p.name AS parent','c.name as name','c.account_id as account_id','c.parent_id as parent_id')->get();
```

i never get the 4th row, isn't that result if i used left join with child_accounts first ?

Comment: First things first, you are really not using laravel eloquent for join. You are using query builder. There is a difference between both. Try to define models properly and then use laravel eloquent. It will reduce joins to only one line.

Comment: @JunaidAhmad edit post

Comment: again bro dont use query builder untill or unless it's impossible with eloquents.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the method **leftJoin()** of query builder, because in your SQL query you are doing a LEFT JOIN, for example:

```
$accounts= DB::table('parent_accounts as p')
               ->leftJoin('child_accounts as c','p.account_id','=','c.parent_id')
               ->select('p.name AS parent','c.name as name','c.account_id as account_id','c.parent_id as parent_id')
               ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some problems with Laravel DB query logic you can perform raw sql [requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) or use simpler version like [this](http://laraveldaily.com/select-with-dbraw-make-your-database-work/)
For example:

```
$accounts= \DB::select(\DB::raw("
           SELECT * from parent_accounts
           LEFT JOIN child_accounts on 
           parent_accounts.account_id=child_accounts.parent_id");
```

But if you really want to understand where is your problem, I'd recommend you to transform your DB query to sql and look if your requests are the same. More [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel#toc-simple-query-debugging).
TLDR;

Simply add `->toSql()` at the end of your query and read the output. Than transform your laravel query to be the same as it's SQL version.